# Trigger Definer Already Same But User Still Denied

Tags: mariadb, trigger, users, database-user

currently I already have user like this `'app_user'@'10.148.0.0/255.255.240.0'`
and I have the trigger with definer like this

```
CREATE DEFINER=`app_user`@`10.148.0.0/255.255.240.0` TRIGGER usertable_delete_audit
```

but when apps insert data i got this error

```
trigger command denied to user 'app_user'@'10.148.0.0/255.255.240.0' for table user table.
```

i already make sure about the grants this user already full grant.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER ON
```

this impact from user with specific host ? i mean because the user have grant like this `10.148.0.0/255.255.240.0`. And the trigger only can give the access from specific ip from server apps ?

my server apps ip 10.148.0.57
i using mariadb version 10.4

Answer (score 0):

Per documentation on [create user](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/#host-name-component), netmasks are only valid on the previous class A,B,C addresses. So masks such as `255.255.240.0` are invalid.

I haven't found a feature request for this feature, however obvious it seems, on https://jira.mariadb.org if you'd like to request one.

Comment: you mean is like `255.0.0.0 or 255.255.0.0 or 255.255.255.0  or 255.255.255.255` ?
and my subnet is invalid ?